# Ordenar array de objetos en swift

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

Necesito ordenar un `array` alfabeticamente en `swift`.

He encontrado este código:

```
var images : [imageFile] = []
images.sort({ $0.fileID > $1.fileID })
```

Pero no se como lo puedo aplicar a mi `array`

Mi código:

```
if let dataFromString = datosJson.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
    let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
    for (index, subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
        for a in 0 ..< subJson.count {
            self.currentlyConstructingObjeto = Objeto()
            self.currentlyConstructingObjeto.nombre = subJson[a]["nombre"].stringValue
            self.currentlyConstructingObjeto.tipo = subJson[a]["tipo"].stringValue
            self.currentlyConstructingObjeto.id = subJson[a]["id"].stringValue
            self.objetos.append(self.currentlyConstructingObjeto)
        }
    }
}
```

El array que tengo que ordenar es `self.objetos`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías probar con esto despues de ya haber rellenado los datos del array , esto lo que hace es ordendar por el campo nombre de menor a mayor.

```
objetos.sorted { $0.nombre < $1.nombre }
```

Answer (score 1):

Para array de objetos:

```
items = items.sorted(by: { (item1, item2) -> Bool in
    return item1.product.name.compare(item2.product.name) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
})
```